# Proving inequality containing multiple square roots

Tags: calculus, inequality, radicals

$$0.8(\sqrt{324-x}-\sqrt{289-x})>0.2(\sqrt{400-x}-\sqrt{361-x})$$

Does anyone know why this condition is satisfied for all x>0?
This equation was given in my lecture slides and I can't wrap my head around it?

They derived this equation from it (in case it helps):
$$0.8\times35 (\frac{\sqrt{324-x}-\sqrt{289-x}}{35})>0.2\times39 (\frac{\sqrt{400-x}-\sqrt{361-x}}{39})$$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For *all* $x > 0$?  Shouldn't we require $x \le 289$ in order to keep the numbers real?

Comment: That might be a good call and makes sense. Mistake in the lecture slides

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of monotonocity and derivatives?

Comment: Yeah. Am I missing an obvious solve?

Comment: Rationalizing the numerators gives a clever way to show it (without any calculus), but probably there are simpler ways.

Comment: @aschepler Can you include your solution, especially if it applies to the much stronger result that I stated?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be helpful for this proof, but the first thing I notice is that 400, 361, 324, 289 = 20², 19², 18², 17².

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $289-x=t$.

Thus, $t\geq0$ and we need to prove that:
$$4\left(\sqrt{35+t}-\sqrt{t}\right)>\sqrt{111+t}-\sqrt{72+t}$$ or
$$\frac{4\cdot35}{\sqrt{35+t}+\sqrt{t}}>\frac{39}{\sqrt{111+t}+\sqrt{72+t}}$$ or
$$140\left(\sqrt{111+t}+\sqrt{72+t}\right)>39\left(\sqrt{35+t}+\sqrt{t}\right),$$ which is obvious.

Comment: As I showed in my solution, we don't need that factor of 4, and equality holds at $ x = 0 , t = 289$. Can we tweak your solution to account for that? It still works for a factor of $39/35$, but can we bring it down to 1?

Answer (score 4):

We will show that $ f(x) = \frac{ \sqrt{ 324 - x } - \sqrt{ 289 - x } } { \sqrt{ 400 - x } - \sqrt{ 361 - x } }  \geq  1$ on $x \in [ 0, 289]$, which is much stronger than your result that $f(x) > \frac{1}{4}$.

Observe that $f(0) = \frac{18 - 17} { 20 - 19 } = 1$.
It remains to show that $f'(x) > 0 $, from which the conclusion follows.

Rationalizing the denominator, $ f(x) = \frac{ (\sqrt{ 324 - x } - \sqrt{ 289 - x }) ( \sqrt{ 400 - x } + \sqrt{ 361 - x } )     } { 39} $.
Let $ a = 400 - x, b = 361 - x, c = 324 - x, d = 289 - x$, we have $ a > b > c > d$.
Applying the product rule and chain rule on derivatives,
$$ \begin{array} {r c l } 
 39 f'(x) & = &  ( -\frac{1}{ 2\sqrt{c}}  + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{d}} ) ( \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} ) + ( \sqrt{c} - \sqrt{d} ) ( -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a} } - \frac{1}{ 2\sqrt{b} } ) \\
& = &\frac{1}{2} (\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} )(\sqrt{c} - \sqrt{d} ) ( \frac{1}{ \sqrt{cd} }- \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ab} } ) \\ 
& > & 0  \end{array} $$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's define $f(x)=0.8(\sqrt{324-x}-\sqrt{289-x})$ and $g(x)=0.2(\sqrt{400-x}-\sqrt{361-x})$, $x\in (0,289]$. Now let's take derivative of both of these $$f'(x)=\frac{2}{5\sqrt{289-x}}-\frac{2}{5\sqrt{324-x}}>0$$ $$g'(x)=\frac{1}{10\sqrt{361-x}}-\frac{1}{10\sqrt{400-x}}>0$$
As you can see since denimonator is clearly larger in the fractions with negative sign in front, so we can conclude that both derivatives are larger than $0$(if you are unsure you can check for yourself it is a simple irrational inequality), which means that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both monotonically increasing on $(0,289]$.

Now we need to show that $f'(x)>g'(x)$, or $\frac{2}{5\sqrt{289-x}}-\frac{2}{5\sqrt{324-x}}>\frac{1}{10\sqrt{361-x}}-\frac{1}{10\sqrt{400-x}}$. If we put that $t=289-x,x\in(0,289]$. We get that $$\frac{2}{5\sqrt{t}}-\frac{2}{5\sqrt{35-t}}>\frac{1}{10\sqrt{72-t}}-\frac{1}{10\sqrt{111-t}}\implies (10\sqrt{35-t}-10\sqrt{t})(100\sqrt{(72-t)(111-t)})<(10\sqrt{72-t}-10\sqrt{111-t})(25\sqrt{t(35-t)})$$
which is clearly true.

Now to finalize our proof we need to show that $\int_{0}^{289}{f'(x)}>\int_{0}^{289}{g'(x)}$. Which is true, since $\int_{0}^{289}{f'(x)}=\frac{4\sqrt{35}-4}{5}>\frac{\sqrt{111}-6\sqrt{2}-1}{5}=\int_{0}^{289}{g'(x)}$. Hence we can conclude that $f(x)>g(x),\forall x \in (0,289]$, meaning your inequality is true.

***Proof was corrected with the help of Calvin Lin (check comments)***

Keep in mind you could also prove this by solving the irrational inequality that's given and  the result should give you the solution $\forall x \in [0,289]$, but that of course is tedious process.

Comment: @CalvinLin could I add something to complete it or is the whole idea wrong

Comment: What you can show is that $f'(x) > g'(x)$ (which is true even for the stronger result), and hence we can do the indefinite integral $ \int_0^X f' > \int_0^X g'$ to conclude that $f(X) - f(0)  > g(X) - g(0)$. Alongside $f(0) = g(0) = 0 $, that gives us $f(X) \geq g(X)$.

Comment: @CalvinLin what if I showed that both functions are convex? Because from the example you've given me that doesn't stand. Also logically it makes some sense, unless you have a counterexample

Comment: No, that's not enough. The "extent" of convexness is important. EG Take $ f(x) = x^2 + 1, g(x) = 3x$  on $[0, 100]$, which is essentially the same counterexample. (Note that this doesn't obey $f' > g'$.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146719/discussion-between-bb-823-and-calvin-lin).